# PHP password verifcation with hash

Tags: php

We have a system where the user logs in to an admin page to make edits however when they are logging in they can log in with any password as long as the username is correct. The following code is in php tags

```
include 'database_conn.php';

$sql = "SELECT passwordHash FROM nmc_users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql); // prepare the sql statement


mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); // execute the query



mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $passWDHash);



if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    if (password_verify($passWD, $passWDHash)) {
        echo "<p>Password correct!</p><a href='logout.php'>Click here to log off</a></p>\n";
    } else {

        echo "<p>Sorry we don't seem to have that username.</p>";
            session_destroy();
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['[url']))
        $url = $_SESSION['url'];
    else
        $url = 'index.php';
    header("location $url");

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
    ?>
```

Would anyone know how to make it so it only logs users in with the correct username and password that.

The password is in our database as well as the usernames. If any more code is needed then please say and I will reply with the relevant pieces.

Comment: What is the question here exactly ?

Comment: My apologies I have edited the OP to include it.

Comment: How are you generating the hashed passwords?

Comment: it is held in a table on phpmyadmin which is why there is an $sql statement (   $sql = "SELECT passwordHash FROM nmc_users WHERE username = ?";  ).

There are 2 sets of usernames and passwords that should be correct however all we need is one of the usernames and any password to log in as an administrator.

Comment: I mean what function are you using on the plaintext passwords to hash them before storing them in the database?

Comment: ah right, they have already been hashed and stored in the table previously.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> session_destroy() destroys all of the data associated with the current
>   session. It does not unset any of the global variables associated with
>   the session, or unset the session cookie.

If `$_SESSION['url']` is set, and the password is wrong, session_destroy() won't unset it. So you're still falling into the success part of the if statement.

Edit: Also, you should be checking authentication on the actual page that requires it. Here, it looks like you're checking on one page and then conditionally redirecting to another. If I type the other page's URL directly into my address bar, will I get that page without an auth check?

Comment: To check that this is indeed the problem, you can do a `die($url);` after the if statement to see if the login message reflects the URL that the script will redirect to. But the redirect shouldn't work anyway since you're echoing some information before the `header()` function.

Comment: We have removed that  if (isset($_SESSION['[url'])) and the else statement that followed in a later version of the code,my mistake. 

However it seems it has not been replaced. Should we put something similar back into the code? Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Please update the question to accurately reflect the current code.

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on @AlexHowansky answer, you need to do a few things here:

First you need to be sure you're using [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) at the beginning of the script to make sure the session is set up correctly.

Second, you need to unset the `$_SESSION` variables to make sure that once the session is destroyed, you can't accss these variables on the current page (they'll be unset on the next page, so you don't have to worry about that).

Third, you'll need to close the mysql connections before redirecting for them to do any good.

Fourth, there was a typo with this: `if (isset($_SESSION['[url']))`

Your [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) redirect also won't work because you're echoing out text before it, which will cause it to fail, but I'll let you fix that.

I'm also not seeing where `$passWD` is coming from, but I'm assuming you have it in there somewhere.

Updated code:

```
include 'database_conn.php';

session_start();

$sql = "SELECT passwordHash FROM nmc_users WHERE username = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql); // prepare the sql statement


mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt); // execute the query



mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $passWDHash);



if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
    if (password_verify($passWD, $passWDHash)) {
        echo "<p>Password correct!</p><a href='logout.php'>Click here to log off</a></p>\n";
    } else {

        echo "<p>Sorry we don't seem to have that username.</p>";
        session_destroy();
        $_SESSION = array();
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['url']))
        $url = $_SESSION['url'];
    else
        $url = 'index.php';

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);

    header("location $url");

}
    ?>
```